# What actually defines the height of a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on an iOS App right now and I want to build a view controller that uses a UITableView to create new events in a calendar (very similarly to how iOS handles event creation in the system calendar, actually). The table view has two sections, the first section holding a date picker and the second section holding two custom cells for entering an event name and notes via a text field and a text view. After playing around with them I managed to force-set them to the right size, but in the process I realized that I don't *actually* understand how iOS calculates individual cell heights, especially in a table view with multiple sections and multiple custom cell classes. So far, I've found a number of things that seem to play a role:

- Contents of a cell, e.g. a text field and its constraints
- Hugging priority and compression resistance priority of a cells content
- Settings for row height and view height in the size inspector of the cell itself:

[image]

- Arrangement and Autolayout settings in the size inspector of the cell
- Settings for the `rowHeight` and `estimatedRowHeight` properties of a UITableViewController

The more I look into it, the more complex and confusing it all gets. Maybe one of you can shed some light on this shady bit of Swift magic?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the rule is that if the table view's `rowHeight` is `UITableView.automaticDimension`, then as long as the `estimatedRowHeight` isn't `0`, you'll get automatic row heights, meaning that the height is determined by the cell's autolayout constraints from the inside out.

The settings can be made in respect to the table view as a whole (in code or in the storyboard) or for a single cell using the `height` delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

- Add your constraints in the cell in right way.
- don't use tableview "height for cell" delegate method.
- use this in your viewDidLoad

---

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I would say that table view has a bit tricky.

Originally it needed to know size of cell before the cell was created.

The height of cell is defined by [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate) optional function [`tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview)

If this function is not defined (or delegate is set to nil) then it will take value of [`tableView.rowHeight`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614852-rowheight)

For performance reasons there was also added [`tableView(_:estimatedHeightForRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614926-tableview) and [`tableView.estimatedRowHeight`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614925-estimatedrowheight)

The idea was not to calculate height of every cell during fast scrolling (such calculation may be costly) and use height that is good enough.

So that are the basics before constraints layout.

Then magic came. You can return `UITableView.automaticDimension` as height (by delegate method or by setting `tableView.rowHeight`). It will force tableView to calculate height from cells' constraints (note that constraints must define that height so very likely you want to set content hugging and resistance priority of every label, and you will encounter 'errors' in storyboard/xib).

Since that operation is costly you Apple forces you to specify estimated height by yourself. Also it's important to set that value to something that makes sense, otherwise things like programatically scroll won't work correctly.